# 2016.1 reintroduces wrong MVVM WPF suggestions

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, resharper

After upgrading to 2016.1, ReSharper is back to suggesting public View Model properties should be made private with 'Member can be made private' suggestion and green squiggly line. These View Model properties must be public in order to be used from the view which does not specify this VM to be it's Data Context in XAML. ReSharper 2016.1 finds these dynamic usages of these properties in XAML of view(s) using the property but still keeps suggesting they should be made private even though doing so would break the data binding.

This was resolved with one of previous versions and now we're back to old invalid behavior... why is this and is there a way to prevent this without using the "Do not show" option for this inspection?

Comment: I can't parse your first (really long) sentence.  Can you break it up into separate sentences, and quote the actual error?

Comment: @PatrickQuirk Rewrote the first paragraph, hope it makes more sense now...

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Go file a bug report.

Comment: ReSharper certainly falls under the category of "software tools commonly used by programmers" as defined in the help center so I fail to see how this is off topic...

Comment: This is a bug in ReSharper. Please could you [log an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=RSRP&clearDraft=true&c=)?